# Error Entry-point asset is required in Configuration Default when importing blackberry 10 sample project?

Tags: blackberry-playbook, blackberry-10

I am getting error, `Entry-point asset is required in Configuration Default`, when I import Blackberry 10 sample app. I can see the error in bar-descriptor.xml in assets tab and there is no configuration. How can I solve that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the drop down SDK selector in your screen shot, it looks like you are running 10.0.9.1101, which is an old version of the SDK. The current Gold SDK is 10.0.9.1673.

Make sure you have downloaded the new one: https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/download/

Once you have, you can change the SDK from the drop down. The setting is saved on a per-workspace basis, and does not get updated automatically when you install a new SDK.

Comment: the link send to the old SDK, how can i fix this?

Answer (score 3):

I think that's not the good answer.
When you import your project dont select Blackberry. Under the General folder, click Existing Projects into Workspace, then click Next.This must work.

Importing a sample

```
1 Download a sample app from https://github.com/blackberry/NDK-Samples
2 Extract the sample zip file to a location on your hard drive.
3 In the IDE, on the File menu, click Import.
4 Under the General folder, click Existing Projects into Workspace, then click Next.
5 Click Finish.
```

The sample should now appear in the Project Explorer.

http://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/bb10/com.qnx.doc.native_sdk.quickstart/topic/running_sample_apps.html